# How to update openSSL in FreeBSD 10?

Tags: freebsd, openssl

I need to update the version of openSSL that I have in FreeBSD 10 (OpenSSL 1.0.1e-freebsd). How can I update that version to a more recent one?
I have owncloud 7 installed with Apache, would updating affect the owncloud service?

Comment: Have you tried using `pkg` ? Here is the documentation : https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html